# Localize tinymce for 2sxc module in dnn

Tags: localization, tinymce, tinymce-4, dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

I found localized JS file on tinymce web site.

Now I am interested how can I integrate this localization into 2sxc module for dotnetnuke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To localize more languages, please contribute to the github project https://github.com/2sic/2sxc-eav-languages

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are using a local install of TinyMCE...

The language files for TinyMCE need to go into the `langs` folder inside of the main folder where TinyMCE itself is located.

For example, to load Spanish I have this file structure:

```
..../tinymce/langs/es.js
```

The second part of this is to add a parameter to the TinyMCE configuration object to tell it to load the language pack:

```
language: 'es'
```

How you get this done in 2sxc - that I don't know as I have no experience with that tool.  If you can figure out where the TinyMCE files are located and how 2sxc creates the TinyMCE configuration object this should be easy to address.

#### If you are using TinyMCE via CDN...

You can specify a different location for the language packs (they are not currently on the CDN).  The `language_url` configuration option allows you to do this:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/localization/#language_url

You can then place the language file(s) wherever you like.  For example:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    language_url: 'http://example.site.com/some/path/you/pick/languages/es.js'
});
```

*Note: You can get language packs from https://www.tinymce.com/download/language-packages/*

Comment: I found language packs, but the problem is finding local instalation of tinymce. Is it posible that the tinymce is loaded from CDN?
If found this code in viewsource : <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js" async=""></script>

Comment: @JernejPirc - see my edit above for CDN use and language packs.

Comment: Thanks @michael-formin I found "tinymce.init" only in file : /DesktopModules/ToSIC_SexyContent/dist/edit/extensions/field-string-wysiwyg-tinymce/set.js also found location of localization in /DesktopModules/ToSIC_SexyContent/dist/i18n/lib/tinymce but unfortunately all this and your info was not enough to make all work